# Plotting multiple means on boxplot in R

Tags: r, mean, boxplot

I have 3 data sets from 3 different csv files of data and am trying to put them in one boxplot with dots at the mean for each box. All is good until I try to add the means
Using the script below, I get the output graph that I want (so this part is all good)...

```
boxplot(a$total, p$total, f$total, 
        names = c("Total", "PR", "FM"), ylab="Evals", 
        col = c("firebrick4", "red3", "tomato1"))
```

But, I run into problems when adding the mean.  Using `points(mean(a$total), pch=18)` adds exactly what I want to the first box ("Total"), but when I do `points(mean(p$total), pch=18)` it adds the mean of `p$total` to the "Total" box and not the "PR" box. Any help is greatly appreciated! [All 3 mean points on first box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecm0n.png)

Comment: Try creating a `means` vector first: `means <- c(mean(a$total), mean(p$total), mean(f$total))` then do `+ points(means, pch = 18)`

Comment: Or use `ggplot` with multiple `stat_summary` geoms. If you add some toy data (try `dput`), then I'll show you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a `ggplot` solution for you:

First, some toy data:

```
a <- data.frame(total = rnorm(50, 4, 0.3))
p <- data.frame(total = rnorm(50, 5, 0.4))
f <- data.frame(total = rnorm(50, 4, 0.25))
```

Now make a plot and use stat_summary to get the means:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(a, aes(y=total, x=NA)) +
  geom_boxplot(data=a,aes(x="Total"),fill="firebrick4") +
  geom_boxplot(data=p,aes(x="PR"),fill="red3") +
  geom_boxplot(data=f,aes(x="FM"),fill="tomato1") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Evals") + 
  stat_summary(data = a, aes(x="Total"), fun.y = "mean", colour = "yellow", size = 3, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(data = p, aes(x="PR"), fun.y = "mean", colour = "yellow", size = 3, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(data = f, aes(x="FM"), fun.y = "mean", colour = "yellow", size = 3, geom = "point")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the start, but I keep getting the error 'Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class integer' Any tips here would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @user6019758 ggplot works only with dataframes. Try converting your data to a dataframe, is I did in the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Yes! Also had to change the names on the data frame columns so they were all the same in my three data frames {names(ff)[names(ff)=='f$total'] <- "total"} - thank you so much :)

Comment: @user6019758 You're very welcome. If you feel your question has been answered, then please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the accept mark left of the answer.